# How do I make a diamond shape using loops with the character "o" in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I would like to print the following pattern in Powershell. I am using VSCode. (I'm new to coding)

```
         o
        ooo
       ooooo
      ooooooo
     ooooooooo
    ooooooooooo
   ooooooooooooo
  ooooooooooooooo
 ooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooo
 ooooooooooooooooo
  ooooooooooooooo
   ooooooooooooo
    ooooooooooo
     ooooooooo
      ooooooo
       ooooo
        ooo
         o
```

But I only know how to print the following using the code below, I am not sure how to invert it to make a diamond:

```
for ($i=0; $i -le 19; $i++) {
    Write-Host (" " * (19-$i)) -NoNewline
    "o " * $i
}
for ($i=1; $i -le 19; $i++) {
    Write-Host (" " * (19-$i)) -NoNewline
    "o" * $i
}
                   
                  o 
                 o o 
                o o o 
               o o o o 
              o o o o o 
             o o o o o o 
            o o o o o o o 
           o o o o o o o o 
          o o o o o o o o o 
         o o o o o o o o o o 
        o o o o o o o o o o o 
       o o o o o o o o o o o o 
      o o o o o o o o o o o o o 
     o o o o o o o o o o o o o o 
    o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o 
   o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o 
  o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o 
 o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o 
o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o o 
                  o
                 oo
                ooo
               oooo
              ooooo
             oooooo
            ooooooo
           oooooooo
          ooooooooo
         oooooooooo
        ooooooooooo
       oooooooooooo
      ooooooooooooo
     oooooooooooooo
    ooooooooooooooo
   oooooooooooooooo
  ooooooooooooooooo
 oooooooooooooooooo
ooooooooooooooooooo
```

Any help or a point in the right direction would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: for ($i=0; $i -le 19; $i++) {
    Write-Host (" " * (19-$i)) -NoNewline;
    "o " * $i;
}
for ($i=19; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
    Write-Host (" " * (19-$i)) -NoNewline;
    " o" * $i;
}
You just invert the second loop backwards

Comment: Important structure of the for() loop: "$i = 0" is the starting code of the loop. Doesn't have to start at 0, doesn't have to do anything really. Doesn't have to initialise variables. "$i -le 19" is the "keep looping while this equals true". "$i++" is the "at the end of each iteration, do this". Doesn't have to add, doesn't have to do much. |||| There is the standards of the loop which you'd want to handle, but the actual requirements is pretty low.

Comment: [Code golf](https://code.golf/diamonds#powershell) is supposed to be *your* best attempt, not stackoverflow's.

Comment: Sorry Doug, I did not know code golf existed. I was just finding code exercises on google and this one gave me trouble so I came here. Code golf seems like an AWESOME resource though so I will be checking it out!

Answer (score 0):

A PowerShell-idiomatic solution that combines use of the [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) statement with `..`, the [range operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#range-operator-) and [array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays) concatenation with [`+`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arithmetic_Operators):

```powershell
foreach ($i in 0..19 + 19..0) {
  ' ' * (19-$i) + 'o ' * $i
}
```

Note:

- `19..0` enumerates from `19`, `18`, ... down to `0`, and it is what creates the lower half of the diamond.
- A *single string* is constructed per iteration (line), which is implicitly output *as data* (whereas [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) is for printing *to the display*), to the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), which by default also prints to the display.

  - Apart from being more concise, it would allow you to capture the entire diamond in an array of strings, by simply doing something like `$diamondLines = foreach ...`

---

As for **what you tried**:

Your second loop must count *backwards*, from `19` down to `0`, i.e. your [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_For) loop must do the equivalent of `19..0` above.

Thus, the first statement inside the loop condition must initialize `$i` to `19`, the second must test whether `$i` is *greater* or equal to `0` (`-ge`), and the third must *decrement* `$i`, i.e. `$i--` rather than `$i++`:

```powershell
for ($i=19; $i -ge 0; $i--) {
  Write-Host (" " * (19-$i)) -NoNewline
  "o " * $i
}
```

As you can see, use of the range operator (`..`), as shown at the top, is a more elegant solution; not only that, it also performs better (which will only matter with high iteration counts).

Comment: Thank you for your help and for also explaining how it works!!! I understand what I am doing a lot more after reading your notes!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it, @Ezze.